# How to Install PHP IMAP Extension on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Using Configuration Files (.ebextensions)?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, imap, ebextensions

Does anyone know how to install and enable PHP IMAP Extension on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using configuration files (.ebextensions)?

I'm using 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.0 running PHP 7.0.16

I've tried several ways as follow:

**1st Way**
I've tried using `files` in configuration file but it doesn't work, the configuration filename is `phpini.config` in `.ebextensions` directory with below setup:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/phpimap.ini":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=imap.so
```

The additional `.ini` files parsed into `phpinfo()` by displaying `/etc/php-7.0.d/phpimap.ini` but the IMAP won't installed.

**2nd Way**
Using `container_command` to install php-imap but i'm getting error.

```
container_commands:
  install_php_imap:
    command: yum install php55-imap
```

Error as image below:
[image: error 2nd way]

**3rd Way**
Using combined `commands` & `files`, it is only success installing **IMAP** and the dependencies (php common) but it doesn't activate the **IMAP**

*a. Create installdependencies.config in my .ebextensions by adding bellow script:*

```
commands:
  install_phpcommon:
    test: '[ ! -f /etc/php.d/curl.ini ] && echo "php common not installed"'
    command:
      yum -y install https://archipelagointernational.s3.amazonaws.com/libs/php70w-common-7.0.16-1.w6.x86_64.rpm
```

*b. Create phpini.config in my .ebextensions by adding bellow script:*

```
commands:
  install_phpimap:
    test: '[ ! -f /etc/php.d/imap.ini ] && echo "php imap not installed"'
    command:
      yum -y install https://archipelagointernational.s3.amazonaws.com/libs/php70w-imap-7.0.16-1.w6.x86_64.rpm

files:
  "/etc/php.d/imap.ini":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=imap.so
```

**4th Way** I'm testing by adding `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `extension=imap.so` to `zzzphp.ini` and only two values are included that are `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. The `extension=imap.so` not included into `zzzphp.ini` file.

[image]
[image]

Below are the script `phpini.config` in `.ebextensions`:

```
commands:
  install_phpimap:
    test: '[ ! -f /etc/php.d/imap.ini ] && echo "php imap not installed"'
    command:
      yum -y install https://archipelagointernational.s3.amazonaws.com/libs/php70w-imap-7.0.16-1.w6.x86_64.rpm

files:
  "/etc/php.d/zzzphp.ini":
    mode: "644"
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 50M
      post_max_size = 58M
      extension=imap.so
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally it's work

Create two files inside .ebextensions as follow:

**installdependencies.config**, install php common if it is required

```
commands:
  01_install_phpcommon:
    command:
      sudo yum -y install php70-common
```

**phpini.config**, install php imap and enable imap

```
commands:
  02_install_phpimap:
    command:
      sudo yum -y install php70-imap

files:
  "/etc/php.d/zzzphp.ini":
    mode: "644"
    content: |
      extension=imap.so
```

Comment: In my case adding the imap.so element gave me "Module 'imap' already loaded - Unknown (0)". All I needed was the yum-install of imap.

Answer (score 2):

For me, below code in phpini.config solved the issue. Please notice the folder names as per php version. My php version is 7.2 hence below code works:

```
commands:
  install_phpimap:
    test: '[ ! -f /etc/php-7.2.d/imap.ini ] && echo "php imap not installed"'
    command:
      sudo yum -y install php72-imap

files:
  "/etc/php-7.2.d/imap.ini":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=imap.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re including the php-imap extension in php’s configuration file, but that’s not sufficient to install it.

You’re going to have to pass something to your EBS provisioning method of choice telling it to install php-imap (or whatever it’s called in that environment) at the system level.

Comment: Could you please give me more technical specific detail? 

Beside above method, i've used `container_commands` as follow:

`container_commands:
  install_php_imap:
    command: yum install php55-imap` 

but there is no luck :(. 

It return error as follow:

`[Instance: i-0e3225fd33d1d6e07] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...======== Install 1 Package (+9 Dependent packages) Total download size: 7.2 M Installed size: 23 M Is this ok [y/d/N]: Exiting on user command Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2017-`

Answer (score 0):

I followed all of the suggestions here but my commands kept on failing because my composer required imap support and the container commands are run after...
Here's what worked for me:

```
packages:
    yum:
        php72-imap.x86_64: []
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) too (I'm running a container with PHP 7.2, it should work for your environment, replace accordly):

```
packages:
    yum:
        php72-imap: []
```